# C# Equality in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, equality

I have a custom object which I have successfully overriden the Equals and HashCode function. Then I have 2 Observable Collections on which I initialise the exact same objects (but with different reference). So I have this code:

```
if (qObjects.Equals(qObjects2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Arrays are equal");
}
```

which I am expecting to return true but returns false. You might say that I did something wrong with Equal and HashCode function. But this is the weird:

```
for (int i = 0; i < qObjects.Count(); i++)
{
    arraysIsEqual = qObjects[i].Equals(qObjects2[i]);

    if (!arraysIsEqual)
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (arraysIsEqual)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Arrays are equal");
}
```

The above code snippet returns true. So what I am missing here?

Comment: *I have successfully overriden the Equals and HashCode function* can you show the `qObjects` class too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are comparing collections with [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx), the [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) objects themselves will be compared. This obviously results in `false`, because the collection's class does not override `Equals` (it's inherited from `Object` so compares references). In order not to have to iterate objects yourself, you can use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. (Confusingly not the SequenceEquals method).

```
if (qObjects.SequenceEqual(qObjects2)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Arrays are equal");
  }
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense since I initialised 2 different ObservableCollections. I don't know why I was expecting Equal to compare the objects. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note, you need to add `using System.Linq;` for this to compile.